# Unblocking a blocked TCP port on a Sonicwall Tz170 firewall

Tags: firewall, nat, sonicwall

Anyone with knowledge of Sonicwall's Tz range might be able to help.

Under Firewall >> Service I create a new Service called "remote tcp conn" and add it to a new Service Group.

Then under Firewall >> Access Rules (WAN to LAN) I create a rule to allow this Service Group access to the LAN.

From my external PC I try to connect to the firewall under the Port given in the Service but the connection fails.

In fact, in the logs the rule that has blocked the connection is called "remote tcp conn", the same name as the Service that is allowed!

Could there be some other conflict or am I not understanding how to allow traffic through the firewall?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the rule?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to create a NAT rule for this traffic.  Namely, you will need to translate any traffic from your external IP address to whichever LAN IP you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to put a check mark in the **`Enable`** box?